# yarn and npm install package shows trouble with your network connection. Retrying

Tags: node.js, npm, package, yarnpkg

I have been trying to fix the problem through many solutions. it has not been fixed yet.
I face the problem my 2 device deskto and laptop both has linux os.
my internet connection stable enough I can browse without problem but whenever I install or do anything on `npm` and `yarn` commands I get this given error on the other hand `pnpm` everything works fine.

I tried restarting the network device, expanding --network-timeout, no proxy and vpn here,`npm` and `yarn` cache clean, updated everything so on.

```
yarn shows 

info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error AggregateError
    at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18)
    at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1177:5)
    at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1687:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)


npm shows

npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fcookie-session failed, reason: 
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/liport/.npm/_logs/2024-01-09T05_28_45_333Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same problem.(I'm using Ubuntu WSL), changing the Node JS version to 18 helped. But some projects require Node JS version 20, so I keep looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: whenever you resolve the issue on node 20 please give us the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem after installing the node 20 version then someone said that I had to install node 18 then the problem would be solved.

If you face the same problem even if you have the node 20 version you can try to install the node 18 version. that should be solved.